# Where did the 'Regster new email' button go?

Tags: email, gerrit

I've setup my own test Gerrit server. I've been able to register my email address and make a couple of commits. However, I deleted my email address in order to get another confirmation email from my server, since I wanted to test the tweak I made to the SMTP server configuration. Going back to my Settings page on the GUI, I noticed the 'Register new email' button had vanished, as pictured below.

[image: Picture of Settings > Contact Information with no 'Register new email' button]

Though the email appears in the drop-down box, my email address *was* deleted, since 1) `Settings > Identities` does not show any email address, and 2) when I try to 'Edit config' on a Project, the GUI pops up the message:

[image: Error message "You have not registered any email addresses"]

I've also tried adding the email using the ssh shell, since I'm admin:

```
$ ssh -p 29418 myUsername@my.server.com gerrit set-account myUsername --add-email foo@bar.com
fatal: realm does not allow adding emails
```

What's the matter?

**EDIT** : Here is my `etc/gerrit.config` file. Yes, I've restarted Gerrit after I've changed it. For sendemail configuration, I've also tried setting the port to 465 and encryption to ssl and restart Gerrit, but it's still the same.

```
[gerrit]
    basePath = git
    serverId = [alphanumeric string]
    canonicalWebUrl = http://my.server.com:8012/
[database]
    type = h2
    database = /home/gerrit2/gerrit/db/ReviewDB
[auth]
    type = OAUTH

[receive]
    enableSignedPush = false
[user]
    name = gerrit2
    email = foo.noreply@gmail.com
[sendemail]
    from = USER
    smtpServer = smtp.gmail.com
    smtpServerPort = 587
    smtpEncryption = tls
    smtpUser = foo.noreply@gmail.com
    smtpPass = [foo.noreply@gmail.com 's Pass]
    sslVerify = false

[container]
    user = root
    javaHome = /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre
[sshd]
    listenAddress = *:29418
[httpd]
    listenUrl = http://*:8012/
[cache]
    directory = cache
[plugin "gerrit-oauth-provider-google-oauth"]
    client-id = [Google client ID]
    link-to-existing-openid-accounts = true
[plugin "gerrit-oauth-provider-github-oauth"]
    client-id = [GitHub client ID]
[plugin "gerrit-oauth-provider-bitbucket-oauth"]
    client-id = [BitBucket client ID]
```

Comment: What is the Gerrit version? Have you clicked in the "foo@bar.com" button?

Comment: @MarceloÁviladeOliveira ssh command yields `gerrit version 2.13.5`. As for the "foo@bar.com" button, it's not a button, just a drop-down box. When I click it, it just shows "foo@bar.com".

Comment: Yes, I was talking about the drop-down box... it should have a "Register New Email" there too. I never saw this issue but I think there's something wrong with your sendemail configuration. Could you check/post the configuration?

Comment: @MarceloÁviladeOliveira Done, I've edited the question. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When
auth.type = OAUTH

You need to add explicitly

```
[oauth]

    allowRegisterNewEmail = true
```

https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/config-gerrit.html#oauth.allowRegisterNewEmail

Comment: Worked for me. Thank you.